# Left join has me stumped

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 2 tables, person and movie

The person table has ID and gender, and the Movie table has ID, movie_type, and movie_attended. genderID and movie_attended can be null.

I want to create a query that will return 3 columns: gender, movie_attended (but it must be a romance movie), and a count of the number of people who have that gender and movie_attended.

Right now I have

```
select person.gender, movie.movie_attended, count(person.gender)
from person left join movie
on person.ID = movie.ID
where movie.movie_type = "romance"
order by person.gender DESC
```

Unfortunately this just gives me one row of information. If I remove the count(person.gender) I get too many rows. Lets say there are only 3 romance movies to choose from. I want my first row to read Male - The Notebook - 12. Second row: Male - Casablanca - 8. Third row: Male - Romeo & Juliet - 2. Fourth row: Male - Null - 2

Then start over with Female

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select gender, count(person.gender), movie.movie_attended
from person left join movie
on person.movie_id = movie.movie_id # or whatever it is called.
where movie.movie_type = "romance"
group by person.gender
```

Comment: That give me 3 rows, one for male, one for female, and one for null. Unfortunately, only 1 movie is being shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you managed to run that query as you are missing a 'group by' statement which is always required when you use an aggregate function. The 'group by' statement should contain the same fields as the 'select' statement, without the aggregate function.

```
select person.gender, movie.movie_attended, count(person.gender)
from person left join movie
on person.ID = movie.ID
where movie.movie_type = "romance"
group by person.gender, movie.movie_attended
order by count (person.gender) DESC
```

I've changed your 'order by' statement as the data which you gave suggest that the query is ordered by the number of results and not by the gender.

It seems strange to me that the person.id should be equal to the movie.id. In terms of database structure, it seems more practical to have a table of people, a table of movies and a joining table built of people.id and movie.id, in which is stored a list of which people who have seen which movies.

Comment: Thank you! I just figured that out myself. Here is the last issue I am dealing with. movie.movie_attended is not showing the "null" values and there definitely should be some. Edit: Should I remove the person.ID = movie.ID? I think that's the problem

Comment: If you remove the 'person.id = movie.id' line, then there will be no link between the tables at all! Assuming that you adopt the three table attitude, then your query will be 'select person.gender, count (*) from person inner join attendance on person.id = attendance.person inner join movies on attendance.movie = movies.id where movies.movie_type = "romance" group by person.gender order by person.gender, count (*) desc'. No need for a left join at all.